# Are the new fighters' names a pun on something?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In *Dragon Ball* series, most names are puns on something. Saiyans are named after vegetables, Gods of destruction are named after alcohol beverages, Bulma and Bura are names of girl clothes, etc.

Now it's been revealed in a Jump magazine (Japanese magazine) that the last 2 members of Universe 6 are

> Namekians, and their names are サオネル (Saoneru) and ピリナ (Pirina)

Are these names a pun on something?

Comment: Do you have the kanji for those (if there is kanji)? I literally can't find Saoneuru in English anywhere on Google, and Purina is a cat food brand. Additionally, can you say what magazine it's from?

Comment: The first name sounds sort of like sayonara (good-bye), but the actual pun is probably a better joke.

Comment: @Pablo Can you provide the characters as they were written in your question, so anyone trying to answer it doesn't need to sort through your comments to figure out how it was actually written?

Comment: @kuwaly It's from Jump Magazine (Japanese). There's a blog which shows the page from the magazine on http://ovicio.com.br/dragon-ball-super-revelados-os-dois-ultimos-lutadores-do-universo-6/

Comment: Can you link twitter here? Pics and names in katakana https://t.co/znLP3bBJOy

Comment: According the Dragon Ball Wiki, Saoneru is a pun for snail, and Pirina is a pun on pilina (a type of mollusk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wiki page, they are named after mollusks.

[Saonel's](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Saonel#Trivia) name could reference snail, while [pirina's](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Pirina#Trivia) name come from pilina