# Is Yamoshi a pun on something?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, japanese-language

All saiyan names are pun on vegetables. Kakaroto (carrot), Vegita (vegetable), Tarble (vegetable), Bardock (Burdock), Totepo (potato), Broly (broccoli), Cabba (cabbage), etc.

Now Akira Toriyama gave recently in an interview the name of the first super saiyan and the first super saiyan god, Yamoshi. Is this a pun on something?

Comment: [Are the new fighters' names a pun on something?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/41712/2869)

Comment: @Darjeeling that was about Saoneru and Pirina, new characters from the Dragon Ball Super anime, this is about Yamoshi a character that barely appeared in Dragon Ball Z, may be the topic names need to be changed for the questions to be more clear, but they are different questions

Comment: I never said it's a dupe or anything just I was just providing a link to similar question in case anyone want to know about the other name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yamoshi is indeed a pun for **Moyashi** ***(もやし)***.

Moyashi is the Japanese term for Bean Sprouts. Bean sprouts are a common ingredient in many Japanese dishes such as stir fries and soups.

Answer (score 3):

Yamoshi's name is a pun on "Moyashi" (もやし), the Japanese term for bean sprouts. This not only fits with Saiyan nomenclature, but also the legends of both Super Saiyan and Super Saiyan God as a whole (with Yamoshi being the "seed" that both legends sprouted from).